# Drop-down does not show design properly

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Drop-down design is not showing properly as I am using Bootstrap with Angular JS.

In the header following js & css are included:

```html
<script src="template_assets/libraries/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="template_assets/libraries/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="template_assets/libraries/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="template_assets/libraries/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="template_assets/libraries/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="template_assets/libraries/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="template_assets/libraries/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="template_assets/libraries/sortable.js"></script>
```

And at footer following js & css included:

Comment: Well, perhaps you can post a bit more code. Till hen I just can give you some experiences from me which include bootstrap dropdowns and angularjs: Trying to fill a bootstrap dropdown with angulars 'ng-repeat' won't work because the dropdown is actually a button with a list under it. When bootstrap renders the ng-repeat is ignored or something. I can't get it working. 
So: Please post some code.

Comment: please add html code and javascript code to help get idea

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Html for drop-down:

It is not showing drop-down properly neither design nor functionality.

```
     <select id="candidateSelect"  class="chosen-select input-md">
        <option value="">Select option</option>
     </select>
```

Attached Screenshot of design-view of DD:https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i1hC.png